# How can I get html content written by JavaScript with Selenium/Python

Tags: python, selenium

I'm doing web-crawling with Selenium and I want to get an element(such as a link) written by JavaScript after Selenium simulating clicking on a fake link.

I tried get_html_source(), but it doesn't include the content written by JavaScript.

Code I've written:

```
    def test_comment_url_fetch(self):
        sel = self.selenium 
        sel.open("/rmrb")
        url = sel.get_location()
        #print url
        if url.startswith('http://login'):
            sel.open("/rmrb")
        i = 1
        while True:
            try:
                if i == 1:
                    sel.click("//div[@class='WB_feed_type SW_fun S_line2']/div/div/div[3]/div/a[4]") 
                    print "click"
                else:
                    XPath = "//div[@class='WB_feed_type SW_fun S_line2'][%d]/div/div/div[3]/div/a[4]"%i
                    sel.click(XPath)
                    print "click"
            except Exception, e:
                print e
                break
            i += 1
        html = sel.get_html_source()
        html_file = open("tmp\\foo.html", 'w')
        html_file.write(html.encode('utf-8'))
        html_file.close()
```

I use a while-loop to click a series of fake links which trigger js-actions to show extra content, and that content is what I want. But sel.get_html_source() didn't give what I want.

Anybody may help? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please include the code you've already written, and indicate which part of it is causing a problem for you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since I usually do post-processing on the fetched nodes I run JavaScript directly in the browser with `execute_script`. For example to get all a-tags:

```
js_code = "return document.getElementsByTagName('a')"
your_elements = sel.execute_script(js_code)
```

Edit: `execute_script` and `get_eval` are equivalent except that `get_eval` performs an implicit return, in `execute_script` it has to be stated explicitly.

Comment: Thanks so much. Though the correct method is `sel.get_eval(js_code)`. And I found this [Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2469701/how-do-i-get-javascript-results-using-selenium?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just call the browser object inside your selenium environment? For example:

```
self.browser.find_elements_by_tag_name("div")
```

Should return you an array of divs. You can also find by class, id, and so on.

**Edit** Below is the code to create your 'browser' object.

```
from selenium import webdriver #The browser object
self.browser = webdriver.Firefox() #I Use firefox, but can do chrome, IE, and safari i believe
```

Then you should be able to do as shown above with the `find_elements_by_tag_name`.

Comment: Sorry I didn't give the whole code of my class. 'self' here is an object of unittest.TestCase, doesn't has the attribute 'browser'. And 'sel' is an object of selenium, I tried but it doesn't has 'browser' neither.

Comment: @Friedmannn I have included the code in my post to create the browser object. Just an extra 2 lines to import and define it. Enjoy.

Comment: oh I see. I'm gonna try it

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use a browser engine which can execute Javascript, such as [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/). Javascript's changes are only visible to clients which can execute Javascript and provide a DOM/Runtime for events to be fired.

Also very close in relation to: [Executing Javascript from Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10136319/executing-javascript-from-python)

Comment: Thanks but Selenium RC just control a real browser, can't I get that from it?