# Selenium: Browser display is different then HTML code

Tags: python, html, google-chrome, selenium

I want to log in to this [page](http://www.anb.org/login.html?url=/articles/home.html%27%29&ip=147.229.179.0&nocookie=0) with Selenium using Python. But the page displayed in the browser is different from page described in the HTML.Firefox or Chrome webdriver gets the same result.

```
chromedriver = "./chromedriver"
os.environ["webdriver.chrome.driver"] = chromedriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)

# OR
#driver = webdriver.Firefox() 


driver.get('http://www.anb.org/login.htmlurl=%2Farticles%2Fhome.html&ip=94.112.189.79&nocookie=0')
# get screenshot of page
driver.get_screenshot_as_file('./01.png')

#get source code of page
print driver.page_source
```

I'm not allowed post the images, but the image is exactly the same as the page displayed in the web-browser.

HTML code from driver:

```
<html><head>
<title>American National Biography Online</title>
<script>
document.write ("<FRAMESET ROWS=\"103,*\" FRAMEBORDER=0 BORDER=0 FRAMESPACING=0>\n");
document.write ("  <FRAME SRC=\"top-home.html\" MARGINWIDTH=0 MARGINHEIGHT=0 SCROLLING=NO>\n");
if (location.search) {
  var url = unescape (location.search);
  url = (new String(url)).substring(1);
  if (url.indexOf ("&") == -1) {
    document.write ("  <FRAME SRC=\"" + url + "\" MARGINWIDTH=0 MARGINHEIGHT=0>\n");
  } else {
    document.write ("  <FRAME SRC=\"main-home.html" + location.search + "\" MARGINWIDTH=0 MARGINHEIGHT=0>\n");
  }
}
else
  document.write ("  <FRAME SRC=\"main-home.html\" NAME=atop MARGINWIDTH=0 MARGINHEIGHT=0>\n");
document.write ("</FRAMESET>\n");
</script></head>
<frameset rows="103,*" frameborder="0" border="0" framespacing="0">
  <frame src="top-home.html" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="NO">
  <frame src="main-home.html?url=%2Farticles%2Fbrowse.html&amp;ip=94.112.189.79&amp;nocookie=0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">
</frameset>

<noframes>
</noframes> 
</html>
```

As you can see, the HTML and the picture do not match.

Maybe problem is with frames?

My configuration:

```
osx 10.8.5
python 2.7.5
chrome browser 28.0.1500.71
firefox browser 24.0
```

I installed the lastest chrome/firefox webdrivers, but I really don't know how to find version.

Comment: I don't see this HTML as being wrong, it simply is HTML provided by server, before it's molested by javascript.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get html content written by JavaScript with Selenium/Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16073626/how-can-i-get-html-content-written-by-javascript-with-selenium-python)

Comment: That is exactly the issue and a reason why the HTML differs. It's not an unknown code, just the original one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The property `page_source` is almost useless: It returns the first version of HTML that the server sent to the browser; it's **not** a copy of the *current* DOM.

The best way to get a copy is to use JavaScript and `innerHTML`:

```
js_code = "return document.getElementsByTagName('html').innerHTML"
your_elements = sel.execute_script(js_code)
```

Also note that `innerHTML` doesn't span `frame` elements. Since you have frames in your code, you need to examine those individually:

```
frames = driver.find_element_by_tag_name("frame")
js_code = "return arguments[0].innerHTML"
your_elements = sel.execute_script(js_code, frames[0])
```

You can also switch to a frame:

```
driver.switch_to_frame("frameName")
```

After that, all code will execute within the context of this frame. Don't forget to switch back.

Comment: but this give me exactly the same html result.
    
    js_code = "return document.getElementsByTagName('html')"
    your_elements = driver.execute_script(js_code)  
    source_code = your_elements[0].get_attribute("outerHTML")
    print source_code

Comment: You did notice the frames in your code? Frames need special handling. See my edits.