# Why python scraping result is different from in browser

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, selenium-chromedriver, referrer

I can browse page `https://www.xiami.com/artist/O9fc383` in browser, but when I parse it by chrome driver, I got different source as below so that I can't scrape that page, what can I do? There is no this form for source in browser.

```
...
<form action="//www.xiami.com:443/artist/O9fc383/_____tmd_____/verify/" id="nc-verify-form" method="GET">
...
<script>
    var referrer=document.referrer;
    if (referrer && referrer.indexOf("__tmd__")===-1 ){
        localStorage.x5referer = document.referrer;
    }else{
        localStorage.x5referer = window.location.href;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: May be the HTML is rendered at the client side, similar to single page applications.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium: Browser display is different then HTML code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19398385/selenium-browser-display-is-different-then-html-code)

Comment: Tried it, different result from browser and scraping.

Answer (score 0):

What lib do you use for scraping? if you use beautiful soup or urllib you cannot scrape code generated by javascript. You will have to use something like silenium
[Scraping a JS-Rendered Page](http://stanford.edu/~mgorkove/cgi-bin/rpython_tutorials/Scraping_a_Webpage_Rendered_by_Javascript_Using_Python.php)

Comment: I use selenium so that I got source, I guess when page is accessed by chrome driver, it load a different content, how can I simulate in browser?

Comment: This post or its duplicate should help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19398385/selenium-browser-display-is-different-then-html-code

Comment: can you browse page `https://www.xiami.com/artist/O9fc383`, then try to scraping it with selenium, and check if they are the same for me?