# Crawl react pages in Java

Tags: java, reactjs, web-crawler

I'm writing a web crawler in Java. The target is a website written in react. I use selenium to render the page to a DOM tree:

```
HtmlUnitDriver unitDriver = new HtmlUnitDriver();
unitDriver.get("https://www.instagram.com/9gag/?hl=en");
WebElement body = unitDriver.findElement(By.tagName("body"));
```

What I get for body is:

```
<body class="">
```

Which is almost nothing. Does selenium render react pages ? I also tried this on `google.com` and it worked fine.

Comment: Is this related to web crawling or selenium?

Comment: I'm using Selenium to do the web crawling

Comment: As far as I know Selenium is for surfing; creating bots, agents and automated testing.

Comment: Do you know any other headless browser in Java that renders react pages ?

Comment: React revuilds DOM on fly with JS. So initially you have just root element where the rest is added by JS. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16073626/how-can-i-get-html-content-written-by-javascript-with-selenium-python

Comment: @StanislavL how should we tell the headless browser to wait ? is this doable using Selenium ?

Comment: yes, selenium has a `pause` function

Comment: Wait? For what? You can set a timeout e.g. for a second and then use browser object or exec scripts to get DOM elements updated by JS.

Comment: @StanislavL I tried `Thead.sleep` right after `unitDriver.get` and it didn't help.